# when defining network using caffe.NetSpec(), Is there a way to "append" from a given prototxt?

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I know that one can (programmably) design a network using `caffe.Netspec()`, and basically the main purpose is to **write** its prototxt.

```
net = caffe.NetSpec()
.. (define) ..
with open('my_network.prototoxt', 'w') as f:
    print(net.to_proto(), file=f)
```

However, instead of starting from scratch, I need to **append** layers based on a **given prototxt**, let's say, `base.prototxt`. What I want is something like

```
net = caffe.NetSpec()
with open('base.prototoxt, 'r') as f:          
    net.from_proto(file=f)            # <== is there something like this?
.. (append) ..
with open('my_network.prototoxt', 'w') as f:   
    print(net.to_proto(), file=f)
```

Could anyone please advise?

Answer (score 0):

You can load the model like:

```
model = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.NetParameter()
input_file = open(filename, 'r')
text_format.Merge(str(input_file.read()), model)
input_file.close()
return model
```

And then copy layers, etc. like:

```
for i in range(0, len(model.layer)):
    new_model.layer.extend([model.layer[i]])
```

This will work also when your `model` / `new_model` is of type

```
model = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.NetParameter()
```

HTH.